# ArgumentOutOfRangeException While Assigning Value To DatagridViewCell

Tags: c#, loops, datagridview, cell

I have a timer and I'm trying to select next row when it ticks. Here's my code:

```
DataGridViewCell cell;

for (int i = lastRowIndex + 1; i < links_dgv.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (links_dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null)
    {
        lastRowIndex = i;
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(lastRowIndex.ToString());
}

cell = links_dgv.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[0];
```

The last line is giving me ArgumentOutOfRangeException. How can I fix this?

**Edit:** Here's error output:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Maybe your lasRowIndex is bigger than the Rows.Count -> the for never runs, and you get the error at the last line

Comment: Your lastRowIndex I assume is set to 0 at start and checked in the if.  You then set it to i that is set to 0+1.  Change your if check to use i not lastRowIndex.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm same thing happens when I do it. I edited the question.

Comment: Can you paste us the exact exception stack?

Comment: @rokkerboci yes, second time it can't get in for loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Does the Rows list has any items?

Comment: If you mean dgv content yes I can see rows in it. l don't know why is this happening but count value seems 1 in debug. https://i.hizliresim.com/1JPQQp.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I got it. The problem was that I'm using another from for datagridview rather than main form, and the form was being opened by main form. I know this is a dirty fix but if I **show** the form after creating form variable, the problem seems fixed:

```
private void pageDelayTmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormEditLinks formEditLinks = new FormEditLinks();
    formEditLinks.Show();
    List<string> list = formEditLinks.GetData();
    if (list != null)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(list[2]);
    }
    formEditLinks.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment due to low rep, but what is the value of lastRowIndex at beginning ? and at end ?

**EDIT :** based on your answer :

Your i starts with value 1
If you have less than 3 rows in links_dgv then you won't enter in your for loop.
-> Your links_dgv.rows[0].cells[0] fires the exception ?

If you have at least 3 rows in links_dgv, you will enter in your for and check if your second row is not null. Is it what you want to do ?
I might be wrong but I think you should write  `int i = lastRowIndex`, instead of `int i = lastRowIndex + 1`

**EDIT2 :**

```
    DataGridViewCell cell = null;

    if (links_dgv.Rows.Count >0)
        for (int i = lastRowIndex; i < links_dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (links_dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null)
            {
                lastRowIndex = i;
                cell = links_dgv.Rows[lastRowIndex].Cells[0];
                break;
            }
    }
```

I have noticed the break instruction, you only want the row located after lastRowIndex right ?
This might be better

```
if (links_dgv.Rows.Count >= lastRowIndex +1)
{
    cell = links_dgv.Rows[lastIndex + 1].Rows[0];
    lastRowIndex++;
}
```

Comment: the value of lastRowIndex is 0

Comment: If you enter in your for loop only once, it means you have 3 rows in your grid.
Is your links_dgv.rows[0].cells[0] null ? :-)

Comment: console writeline outputs: DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=0 }

Comment: Did you try to replace lastRowIndex + 1 by lastRowIndex when you initialize i ?

Comment: Yes I did, still the same.

Comment: I modified the code, check my EDIT2 it should work, let me know

Comment: It underlines : new DataGridViewCell();

Comment: DataGridViewCell is an abstract class, let's set your cell to null if your gridview has no value inside. (I modified the code)

Comment: I tried it, it's giving me the same error for the last line.

Comment: If this new edit does not work, please, provide some debug informations about the error you encounter :-)  (I already saw the one you posted in comment, but it doesn't help, I would like to have information about your links_dgv)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/nikel/d1c4cdee067b34bf0ce2d57aa3695c6c and simpler one: https://gist.github.com/nikel/ad354d43f2f4f323f0e5fa95a6fe3b11 and the output when the error occurs: https://gist.github.com/nikel/7d29df07fd6edadf1f59c71adbcf964a

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have access to sub-informations such as rows.count :-(

-> Can you please create a form with your grid and your code, zip it and provide a link so I can download and check it ?

Comment: Thank you, I will update you in the evening, I'm currently at office and proxy is blocking the link!

Comment: Re, the code I wrote in EDIT1 is working on my laptop. You forgot to delete "-1" at the condition in the for loop :  i <links_dgv.Rows.Count

Comment: I did it but I'm getting error for this line: if (links_dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0] != null)